# Best Practice to control access to service/screen access during run time in Spring based web application

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servlet-filters

I  manage few spring based web applications. for example if my client is a  flex application, with many modules/screens.  Access to the screen or page or even a spring service is controlled by spring security based on the user role.

At certain time we may want to block access to that screen or service  completely irrespective of the access granted by role. May be we want to take down a specific page/screen or a service for maintenance.  and enable it after certain time. What is the best practice to achieve it.  I do not want to restart the application.

I think of using some filter, so every request will pass through the filter and this filter will have the logic to check , if the current operation or view is allowed or disabled.
Is this the better way to handle it. or Is there any other solution. 
What is the best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlet filtler is a good choice if you want to block pages known by URL. This solution is simple and pretty straightforward.

Spring aspect will be better if you want to block services. Just wrap classes you would like to block and perform a check prior to calling it. Throw a specific exception that you can handle in the presentation layer.

We implemented a similar feature once in REST-based application. A global filter/aspect blocks all non-GET methods effectively switching an application to read-only mode.

Comment: As you said filters does not mix with your business code. so it is clean. where as aspect needs lot of annotations. I am yet to learn Spring AOP, But I think the aspect has to be defined, before the application started. Is it possible to control, specific  method/service access, during run time, with out restart/update of application.  Can you give me some pointer, or links, on how it is done.

Comment: @user1057094 You do not need to do it from scratch. Just customize the security interceptors. For web resource it should be FilterSecurityInterceptor. For services, check MethodSecurityInterceptor or AspectJMethodSecurityInterceptor.

Comment: hi this interceptor, works only with spring mvc client ?  or any type of client ?  ( i read this post filter vs interceptor http://www.jsecurity.org/node/46  )

Comment: If my app is having multiple DispatcherServlets one for spring MVC other for flex clients(blazeds) will FilterSecurityInterceptor work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always front your application with an apache httpd (or some other reverse-proxy web-front) and control access to individual URL-patterns there. That also gives you the added benefit that you can actually have a nice maitenance-page up while you take down the entire application.

Comment: apache is a good option, but I would like to have a java/spring based solution, within the application.